# Debbugging freezes with a unknown problem

Tags: android, android-studio

My debugger doesn't work it stops at some point and it fresses not allowing any interaction with my app in debug mode. The app is fine it runs perfectly when I run it on any emulator. I have tried Clean Project, Rebuild and Even invalidate caches and Restart and none of these solved my problem. I checked a lot of stack Overflow post on this but none of them really answers the question in a good manner.

PLEASE I THINK THIS IS A MATTER OF ANDROID STUDIO TO PROVIDE WITH THE ANSWER. IF YOU ARE NOT FROM THE ANDROID STUDIO TEAM DO NOT ANSWER!!!. AS I SAID NO SOLUTION IS AVAILABLE ONLINE PLEASE ANSWER IF YOU REALLY FOUND A SOLUTION.

The problem is i see in the debugger

```
I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
```

Comment: Plz check whether you have marked too many breakpoints, if yes then plz remove all of them.

Comment: i dont have any breakpoints :(

Comment: check if something here can help you 
 https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug    The GC is for Garbage collection so there might be a memory issue somewhere...check the link and try to change the GC type etc.